# UPPER function with an IN Statement

Tags: mysql

I need to use an UPPER function with an IN function in an SQL query, can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? I am also using a COUNTfunction which may be complicating matters :S

```
SELECT pepp.employee_number||'|'||pepp.full_name||'|'||pepp.person_id||'|'||cnt.cn  Counted
FROM apps.per_all_people_f pepp
, (SELECT Count (person_id)CN, Upper (full_name)  full_name
FROM apps.per_all_people_f  pepp
WHERE 1=1
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN effective_STArt_date AND effective_end_date 
group BY Upper (full_name)  
ORDER BY  Count (person_id) DESC, full_name) CNT
WHERE 1=1
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN pepp.effective_start_date AND pepp.effective_end_date
AND Upper (pepp.full_name) = cnt.full_name
and Upper (pepp.full_name) IN UPPER('Bloggs, Mr. Joe',
'Name, Ms. Anne');
```

It works for the single name, but not for 2 or more...

Any help would be appreciated .....

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: Carefull, using upper() or similiar functions in predicates is dangerous as it might lead to not-used index access (but on the other hand, you might not need those). Also be carefull with using upper/lower in some locales it is not the same as case insensitive compare. Might be better to use collate.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead

```
IN (UPPER('Bloggs, Mr. Joe'),UPPER('Name, Ms. Anne'))
```

Not tested but im pretty sure that's the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

try to change :-

```
UPPER('Bloggs, Mr. Joe','Name, Ms. Anne') into 
(Upper('Bloggs, Mr. Joe'),Upper('Name, Ms. Anne'));
```